# Servlet filter insists that there's no response text

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

My filter is supposed to edit the HTML of a response. But when I navigate to a page it does nothing because

```
newResponse.toString();
```

returns `null`.

Further debugging shows that within that `toString` method, `writer` is `null`

Here is the section that seems to be the problem:

```
public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
    if (getWriterCalled) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("getWriter already called");
    }

    getOutputStreamCalled = true;
    return super.getOutputStream();
  }

  public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
    if (writer != null) {
      return writer;
    }
    if (getOutputStreamCalled) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("getOutputStream already called");
    }
    getWriterCalled = true;
    writer = new PrintWriter(charWriter);
    return writer;
  }

  public String toString() {
    String s = null;

    if (writer != null) {
      s = charWriter.toString();
    }
    return s;
  }
}
```

The full code is here:

[Filter that uses a response wrapper to convert all output to uppercase](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/Filterthatusesaresponsewrappertoconvertalloutputtouppercase.htm)

Comment: You've wrapped the `Writer` but not the `OutputStream`. Your servlet is probably writing directly to the `OutputStream`. Use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, servlet filter chain is invoked on HTTP request **before** it reaches the destination (for example - servlet). As you use Filter to get the content which is produced by a request destination point, you get `null` because it will exist only in future. 
But there is an adequate solution, mentioned in docs (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html).
Just make so that your response wrapper decorated the access to the HttpServletResponse's content. For example - override the default writer with your custom, which will detect the letters and uppercase them at his write() method.

Comment: I looked at that link, but I don't see the solution that you mention.

Comment: There was a sentence "3. Optionally wrap the response object with a custom implementation to filter content or headers for output filtering " at doFilter() description. I just tried to develop that idea. Really think about a input or output stream overriding/chaining.

Comment: Thank you. It turns out my problem was much easier than that. But the link was useful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The page I was trying to filter was `index.html`.

It seems that the filter can only edit the response for a page ending in `.jsp`.

Comment: That's just a matter of fixing the URL pattern in filter mapping.

Comment: @BalusC Currently url-pattern is set to `/*`. Why does that accept only `.jsp` files?